# Character replacement mask over a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to apply a replacement mask over a string in javascript. The mask is a user input with the following syntax:

- '#' indicates that the character at the same position in the input string should be left untouched
- Any other value indicates that the character at the same position in the input string should be replace by this value

I have come up with the following code that appears to be working but I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve this with a single regular expression or any other way (no library please).

Thank you

```
var reference = '123-45678-000';
var mask ='###W#####-9##';
var newReference = mask;

while ((match = /#{1}/.exec(newReference)) != null) {
   newReference =  newReference.substring(0, match.index) + reference.substring(match.index,match.index+1) + newReference.substring(match.index + 1);
}
console.log("old : " +  reference);      //prints 123-45678-000
console.log("mask: " +  mask);           //prints ###W######9##
console.log("new : " +  newReference);   //prints 123W45678-900
```

Comment: What should be done if the lengths don't match. Using your sample mask of `###W#####-9##`, what should happen if I only enter `12` as the input?

Comment: @dman Good point. I should have clarified that I have logic (not shown on snippet) that ensures that the input and the mask are the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
newReference = mask.replace(/#/g,function(m,o) {return reference[o];});
```

Comment: Thank you ! I read the doc earlier but it did not click for me at the time. Nice use of the offset property. Some references here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1):

```
var reference = '123-45678-000';
var mask ='###W#####-9##';
var newReference = "";

for (var n=0;n<reference.length;n++){
    newReference+=( mask.charAt(n) == '#' )?reference.charAt(n):mask.charAt(n);
}
```